# Complex integral square

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Let $\alpha$ be the closed curve along the square with vertices at $1, i, -1, -i$.
>
> Give an explicit parametrization for $\alpha$ and calculate
>   $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\alpha\frac{dz}{z}$$

I got this parametrizations:
$$\alpha(t) = \begin{cases} 1+(i-1)t & 0\leq t\leq 1\\ i+(-1-i)(t-1) & 1\leq t\leq 2\\ -1+(-i+1)(t-2) & 2\leq t\leq 3\\ -i+(1+i)(t-3) & t\leq 3\leq 4\end{cases}$$
So far so good, but now I want to find the asked integral. I want to compute the four integrals apart. For the first part of the path we thus have $\int_0^1\frac{i-1}{1+(i-1)t}dt$. But how can I calculate a primitive?

Comment: Please take the time to go through our [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It helps make your question much more readable.

Comment: More to the point (and disconnected from @AlexR's answer), a good question to ask in this context is: where can you find a primitive to $\frac{1}{z}$? Can you brake $\alpha$ into two or more pieces, where each is contained in such a domain?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Substitute $u = \frac t{i-1}$ and see what happens.